# angular2 not loading the component on entering the url path

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, routes, url-routing

When trying to load a specific component by entering it's url path the app doesn't load the component. It only shows the loading message and I don't get any errors mentioned in the console.

But if I try loading the same component by redirecting the base url to the path, then everything works fine and am redirected.

I have no idea what is causing this weird behavior. Am using webpack2 as my bundler.

This is my code:

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/processor', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  template: `
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;
    public constructor(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
        this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';

import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routes';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, routing
   ],
  declarations: [
      AppComponent, LoginComponent
   ],
  providers: [ appRoutingProviders ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=UTF-8>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="global.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <base href="/">
    </head>
    <body>
        <app>
            Loading ...
        </app>
    </body>
</html>
```

So basically if I load http://localhost:3000/ then I get my LoginComponent content displayed and the url is changed to http://localhost:3000/login. But I if try loading http://localhost:3000/login from the start than I don't get anything beside the 'loading' msg defined the index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** You can use **HashLocationStrategy(#)**  for that *server-side routes* configuration is not needed.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  //<<<===here
  ],
   ...
})
```

Now, If you refresh, you will be able to see the same page.

**2)** If you are using **pathLocationStrategy(/)**, *server-side routes* configuration is needed else refreshing page will not bring the same page.